# Is it possible to call JSF events from an Inner Bean?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

i want to know if it is possible to call JSF events, such as a valueChangeListener and actionListener from an Inner bean, that is, a bean that is an objetc inside some other Managed Bean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You only need to make sure that the instance is available during the actual request.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText valueChangeListener="#{bean.nested.change}" />
```

in combination with

```
public class Bean {
    private Nested nested; // +getter
}
```

and

```
public class Nested {
    public void change(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is **not** going to work if `Nested` is not been instantiated in `Bean`. The `#{bean.nested}` would then return null and the method is unreachable. Thus, ensure that it is been instantiated:

```
public class Bean {
    private Nested nested = new Nested(); // +getter
}
```

EL namely won't do that for you.